# How to prevent a SQL INNER JOIN with ON cond1 OR cond2 to ignore keys and do a full table scan

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have a simple query which works not as expected. In spite of an index, the join part of the query ignores it and does a full table scan. Here is the query

```
SELECT m0.id_field, 
       attr_73217_   
  FROM object_73195_ o
       INNER JOIN master_slave m0 
           ON  (   m0.id_object = 73130 
                OR m0.id_object = 82344) 
           AND (   m0.id_master = 73195 
                OR m0.id_master = 82413) 
           AND m0.id_slave_field = o.id 
ORDER BY
       o.id_order
```

The `EXPLAIN` command returns the following lines:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                                               key     key_len ref                       rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE      m0      ALL     id_object,id_master,id_slave_field,id_slave_field_2,id_object_2,id_object_3 \N      \N      \N                        2782  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      o       eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                                     PRIMARY 8       project.m0.id_slave_field 1     Using where
```

As you can see, it does not uses the key, even though it was created like this:

```
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_object,id_master,id_slave_field);
```

The interesting thing is that if I comment out `m0.id_field` from the `SELECT` part, then first select type (given by explain command) turns into `range`, the query starts to use a key `id_object_3` and what is also very important - it now scans a less number of rows in the `master_slave` table. But the catch is, I need `m0.id_field` in my `select` part. I guess I need to do something with my indices, but I do not know what exactly.

**EDIT**
I tried to add another keys like this:

```
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_field); 
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_object);
```

But the `EXPLAIN` command returns the very same set of rows - no keys and full table scan. The whole trouble is caused by m0.id_field in the `select` part.

**EDIT**

I just added a bunch of indices to master_slave table:

```
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_field,id_object,id_master,id_slave_field);
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_object,id_field,id_master,id_slave_field);
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_object,id_master,id_field,id_slave_field);
ALTER TABLE master_slave ADD INDEX (id_object,id_master,id_slave_field,id_field);
```

Each index resulted to lowering the number of scanned rows. My special thanks to **kordirko**.

Comment: Move this `(m0.id_object = 73130 OR m0.id_object = 82344) AND ( m0.id_master = 73195 OR m0.id_master = 82413)` to the `WHERE` and see what happens

Comment: And what should be done with ON part instead? ON 1?

Comment: `ON m0.id_slave_field = o.id` should be enough

Comment: `SELECT m0.id_field, attr_73217_  FROM object_73195_ o INNER JOIN master_slave m0 ON m0.id_slave_field = o.id WHERE  (m0.id_object = 73130 OR m0.id_object = 82344) AND (m0.id_master = 73195 OR m0.id_master = 82413) ORDER BY o.id_order`

Comment: I checked. Explain command returns the same set of rows. Nothing changed

Comment: But I guess in this case there should be another index?

Comment: Could you post definitions of indexes ? It's hard to guess, looking on index names in the explain, what columns do they have.

Comment: How many rows are there on master_slave, and how many match the 2 fields you are checking?

Comment: There are exactly 2782 rows.

Comment: @kordirko I posted the way how indices were created

Comment: Only 947 rows match them

Comment: 947/2782 = 34% of the table, in this case the full table scan is probably better option, since a direct sequential access costs less than a random table access using the index.

Comment: @kordirko The catch is, if I add m0.id_field to the select part, then the full table scan is done, otherwise - not. So, if it was "better option" as you are saying, then the situation would be the same in both cases. I see no logic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jacobian - this is not an answer to your question
or mayby only a partial answer.
I am writing here because my explanation is too long and doesn't fit into the comment.

---

If the select statement does not contain `m0.id_field`, then the query refers only to 3 fields from m0 table:  id_object,id_master,id_slave_field.
Since there exist a **covering index** on that table for these 3 columns, then the obvious choice is to scan this index instead of the table. The index (the index file on the disk) is much more smaller than the table and reading the index costs less than reading the table.

---

We say **covering index** when the index contains all required columns retrieved by the query, and the query can retrieve all information directly from the index --> see : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index

---

If you add `m0.id_field` to the select clause, then there is no index that contains all of these 4 columns, and in this case the query must read values of this column from the table.
It can do it in two ways:
1. using the index to filter rows, then access rows in the table using primary keys obtained from the index (row by row - random access).
2. scanning the whole table, without touching any index
The first method is good in cases where the expected number of rows is small (<5% maybe <10% of the table). Remember that DBMS cannot read one row from the disk, it always must read a whole page! To obtain one row with size, for example, 50 bytes, it must read the whole page, which size is 5k or 10k or more (a length of the page depends on settings). There are some optimization possible, for example MySql, while scanning the index, first collects PK values in the memory, then sorts them, and finally scans the table using these PKs in ascending order, to minimise a number of pages retrieved from the disk. But it is still the random access, which is slower than the sequential reading (the disk must seek heads to random track, instead of reading a track by track)
If an expected number of rows is huge ( 34% of the table in our case ), using the second method (scaning the whole table) is much more cheaper than first scanning and filtering the index, then sort a result of the scan, then access the table using PK retrieved from the index. The final number of disk pages that must be read from the disk is less (scanning the index also must reads some pages from the disk).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this experience! I added extra info to my question. Please, have a look.